# UPDATE query using multiple AND conditions slow in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table (~2 million rows) based on another table(10k rows). However, my update query is taking extremely long(30 mins) without any outputs as of yet. Is there a way to optimise this query?

```
 UPDATE global_mobility_report 
 SET 
    global_mobility_report.locationID1 = (SELECT 
            geography.locationID
        FROM
            geography
        WHERE
            global_mobility_report.country_region = geography.country_region
                AND global_mobility_report.sub_region_1 = geography.sub_region_1
                AND global_mobility_report.sub_region_2 = geography.sub_region_2
                AND global_mobility_report.metro_area = geography.metro_area
                AND global_mobility_report.iso_3166_2_code = geography.iso_3166_2_code
                AND global_mobility_report.census_fips_code = geography.census_fips_code);
```

Comment: @Akina im sorry, can i ask for more elaboration? i am not seeing where i made a mistake

Comment: Use [UPDATE statement -> Multiple-table syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: *I am trying to update a table (~2 million rows) based on another table(10k rows).* This query must set `global_mobility_report.locationID1` to NULL for all rows which have no matched row in `geography`. *without any outputs* What do you want to receive back from UPDATE query? this is not SELECT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply indexed the country_region,
sub_region_1,
sub_region_2,
metro_area,
iso_3166_2_code,
census_fips_code columns and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE global_mobility_report 
JOIN geography USING ( country_region,
                       sub_region_1,
                       sub_region_2,
                       metro_area,
                       iso_3166_2_code,
                       census_fips_code )
SET global_mobility_report.locationID1 = geography.locationID;
```

The presence of according index will improve.

The rows in `global_mobility_report` which have no according row in `geography` will not be updated (stay unchanged). If you need them to be set to NULL then use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I will give this query a go and see the processing time. Thank you.

Comment: may i ask if this query will take several hours or more? I have been running for an hour or so and there is still no output...

Comment: @CheeJiaYuan Without suitable index this query may be too long - that's true. But when the index is present - it must be fast (for 2kk and 10k tables - few minutes). The best way - the index by the whole joining expression (with any columns order).